# DB to JSP : what is the best way about number format problems?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, oracle, jsp

I have a question about number format from oracle DB.

It just called by DAO and pass to web page.

My sql queries like this.

```
to_char(some_number, 'FM999,999,999,999.999')
```

I want to remove below '.' values when it does not contain usable values.

if some_number = 99999 then
web browser shows to me like this. '99,999.'

I don't want to show '.' But sometimes this number contains decimals.

How and where I controll this number?

DB query ? JAVA(DAO) ? JS(JQuery)

What is the best way to solve this format problem.

I need your wise opinion.

Thank you for reading it. Have a good day, Seriously.

Comment: Never rely on JS for such formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer it when numbers line up at the decimal point.  That is, if some values of an attribute are displayed to three decimals places I think *all* values for that attribute should be displayed to three decimal places.  Anything else is confusing to the user.

However, it is possible to trim the trailing zeroes from integer values, by testing each value to see whether it is an integer and varying the format mask accordingly:

```
SQL> select col1
  2         , case when trunc(col1) = col1 then to_char(col1, 'FM999,999,999,999')
  3                else to_char(col1, 'FM999,999,999,999.999') end as col1_ch
  4  from t23
  5  /

      COL1 COL1_CH
---------- --------------------
       101 101
    42.789 42.789

SQL>
```

If you wish to apply some alignment to the output you can use the LPAD() function.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions095.htm#i1371196)